# Problem with characters encoding text buffer from process

Tags: php, windows, encoding, utf-8, console

Can't set correct encoding to outptut text buffer of the console process at russian windows 10. Please help with it. Need to convert console output into UTF-8 encoding and output in browser.

**I'm tried different encodings:**

- utf-16 -> utf-8
- ascii -> utf-8
- windows-1251 -> utf-8
- windows-1252 -> utf-8

But no luck :(

It's output only **english characters** and numbers. **No russian symbols**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$cmd = "ping mail.ru";

execAndOutput($cmd);

function execAndOutput($cmd){
    $process = popen($cmd, 'r'); 

    while($out = fgets($process, 2048)) { 
        $out = mb_convert_encoding($out, "utf-8", "windows-1251");
        echo $out."<br>\n"; 
        ob_flush();flush(); 
    } 
    pclose($process); 
} ?>
```

With encoding 1251 I've got this in output:

```
ЋЎ¬Ґ­ Ї ЄҐв ¬Ё б mail.ru [94.100.180.202] б 32 Ў ©в ¬Ё ¤ ­­ле: 
ЋвўҐв ®в 94.100.180.202: зЁб«® Ў ©в=32 ўаҐ¬п=118¬б TTL=49 
ЋвўҐв ®в 94.100.180.202: зЁб«® Ў ©в=32 ўаҐ¬п=118¬б TTL=49 

‘в вЁбвЁЄ  Ping ¤«п 94.100.180.202: 
Џ ЄҐв®ў: ®вЇа ў«Ґ­® = 4, Ї®«гзҐ­® = 4, Ї®вҐап­® = 0 
(0% Ї®вҐам) 
ЏаЁЎ«Ё§ЁвҐ«м­®Ґ ўаҐ¬п ЇаЁҐ¬ -ЇҐаҐ¤ зЁ ў ¬б: 
ЊЁ­Ё¬ «м­®Ґ = 118¬бҐЄ, Њ ЄбЁ¬ «м­®Ґ = 120 ¬бҐЄ, ‘аҐ¤­ҐҐ = 118 ¬бҐЄ
```

Without any encoding convertion I've got this:

```
����� ����⠬� � mail.ru [94.100.180.200] � 32 ���⠬� ������: 
�⢥� �� 94.100.180.200: �᫮ ����=32 �६�=113�� TTL=46 
�⢥� �� 94.100.180.200: �᫮ ����=32 �६�=170�� TTL=46 

����⨪� Ping ��� 94.100.180.200: 
����⮢: ��ࠢ���� = 4, ����祭� = 4, ����ﭮ = 0 
(0% �����) 
�ਡ����⥫쭮� �६� �ਥ��-��।�� � ��: 
�������쭮� = 109�ᥪ, ���ᨬ��쭮� = 170 �ᥪ, �।��� = 135 �ᥪ
```

Expected (copied from windows terminal):

```
Обмен пакетами с 127.0.0.1 по с 32 байтами данных:
Ответ от 127.0.0.1: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=128
Ответ от 127.0.0.1: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=128

Статистика Ping для 127.0.0.1:
    Пакетов: отправлено = 4, получено = 4, потеряно = 0
    (0% потерь)
Приблизительное время приема-передачи в мс:
    Минимальное = 0мсек, Максимальное = 0 мсек, Среднее = 0 мсек
```

I'm want to get **Russian symbols** from console in **browser**.

Comment: Do you get any output for the russian characters, such as questionmarks or tofu rectangles? Can you include an example, please?

Comment: Have a try using `$out = mb_convert_encoding($out, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-5");`

Comment: @Dragonthoughts. I'm added examples of output into my question

Comment: @arkascha. I'm tried your version but no luck others strange symbols :(

Comment: Try simplifying the problem. Potentially you could be corrupting the data on reading or writing. If you eliminate reading from a file, but output a string that you create in code, how does your program behave?

Comment: Looks like the data you have is not really encoded the way you claim. How did you find out the encoding?

Comment: Ah, ok, I only now saw your own answer which actually answers my question above: what the actual encoding is. So it turns out you started of with false assumptions. Happens ;-)

Comment: @arkascha I don't know what the encoding windows use by default... So it is my primary question what encoding windows use. Anyway thanks for trying help to me.

Comment: I am not very experienced with MS-Windows. That system was the last to switch to Unicode when Linux and also MacOS had made that transition long before, but I actually thought that the default in current MS-Windows installations is UTF-8 these days. Though I certainly may be wrong in that. And also the encoding used by some programs or tasks or processes may very well be different, that system is well known for old components still being around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fonded solution for this.

[Console settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NN5x.jpg)

In windows console settings i found the current encoding is CP866 and add it to mb_encoding.

**For Russian symbols in console:**

```
mb_convert_encoding($out, 'utf-8', 'cp866');
```

or

```
 iconv('cp866', 'utf-8', $out);
```

Check your **console settings** to figuraute **what encoding it use**.

Now all works like a sharm. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `iconv` function

```
iconv('from_encoding', 'to_encoding',$str);
```

also you can correct your encoding like this

```
iconv('utf-8', 'utf-8//IGNORE',$str);
```

Comment: I'm tried your version with iconv. But got same result as mb_convert. //IGNORE TAG - just removed all stranged symbols form string and output english letters and numbers.

Comment: I have no meta tags on page or any others html blocks. I'm just set header with "header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');"